# NodeJS Kafka Consumer is getting duplicate messages?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using `Kafka-Node` in my NodeJS application to both produce and consume messages. I start a consumer that is waiting for my topic. I then start the producer and send the messages to Kafka. My consumer is inserting each one of these messages into a Postgres database.

For a single consumer, this is working fine.

When I stop the consumer and keep producing, I restart the consumer about 30 seconds later. I noticed there is about a dozen or so messages that were already inserted into the DB from the original consumer.

I am assuming that when I killed the consumer, there were offsets that had not yet been committed and that’s why the second consumer is picking them up?

What is the best way to handle this situation?

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var utilities = require('./utilities');
var topics = ['test-ingest', 'test-ingest2'];
var groupName = 'test';

var options = {
    groupId: groupName,
    autoCommit: false,
    sessionTimeout: 15000,
    fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
    protocol: ['roundrobin'],
    fromOffset: 'latest',
    outOfRangeOffset: 'earliest'
};

var consumerGroup = new kafka.ConsumerGroup(options, topics);

// Print the message
consumerGroup.on('message', function (message) {

    // Submit our message into postgres - return a promise
    utilities.storeRecord(message).then((dbResult) => {

        // Commit the offset
        consumerGroup.commit((error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Commit success: ', data);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell why `fromOffset: 'latest'` does not work for you. An easy workaround is to use `offset.fetchLatestOffsets` in order to fetch the latest offset and then consume from that point onwards.

Comment: Hm, for some reason this seems to have duplicated the messages at the very beginning now instead once I stopped and restarted the consumer,

Comment: @SBB Do you use the same consumer group?

Comment: Yeah, I am restarting the same consumer file which has the group name defined in it `var groupName = 'test';`

Comment: Sadly no, prior to your suggestion, the duplicates occurred just before the last couple of records were inserted into the DB. With your suggestion, the duplicates happened at the very beginning of the records that were inserted.

Comment: @SBB By the way, where did you define your Kafka hosts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196273/discussion-between-sbb-and-giorgos-myrianthous).

Comment: @SBB Any luck with this?

Comment: Not quite - I still seem to be getting overlap with whichever way I do it. Instead, I set it to `latest` for both of them, and then I pass a uniqueID along with the message that it stored with the record in my table. If a record already exists with this ID, it ignores the insert to prevent the duplicates. Not sure if this is a typical work-around but seems to work so far.